# C# use Process.Start in Thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I make a thread which do some work and run shutdown.exe to shutdown the pc.

```
Worker work = new Worker();
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(work.DoWork));
thread.Start();
```

and the method DoWork()

```
public void DoWork()
{
        /* Do some thing */

        // This will shutdown the PC
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\shutdown.exe", "-s -t 5");
        Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

If i call method work.DoWork() in main thread, the PC'll shutdown.
But if i put it in thread using thread.Start(), the pc won't shutdown.

Edit:
Found my mistake. I create a thread-safe call method to read the checkbox which always return false

```
    delegate bool GetcbShutdownCheckedValueCallback();

    public bool GetcbShutdownCheckedValue()
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.lblCraftRemain.InvokeRequired)
        {
            GetcbShutdownCheckedValueCallback d = new GetcbShutdownCheckedValueCallback(GetcbShutdownCheckedValue);
            this.Invoke(d);
        }
        else
        {
            return cbShutdown.Checked;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I call the method to check if the check box is checked then shutdown. So actually the code isn't executed.

Comment: Can you try to put a breakpoint in DoWork()? That way you can see if the code gets executed. And do you use "work" after creating the thread? It is possible that C# cleans the object because it isn't used any more.

Comment: Are you perhaps marking your thread as a [background thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) (`IsBackground = true`), and exiting your process after you call `thread.Start()`? Bit of a longshot, but that'd cause the situation you describe.

Comment: If you solved your own problem you can answer your own question and mark it accepted, this will keep the question from re-appearing as "No accepted answer" on the front page every few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shut the computer down it's better to call Win32's `ExitWindows` function rather than running the `shutdown.exe` program.

There's MSDN documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And the C# P/Invoke signature here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.exitwindowsex